# Timestamp in Ethereum

Tags: solidity, transactions, blocks, timestamp, datetime

I have a smart contract where the user inputs temperature readings, I'd like to add a time stamp to relate those reading with a current time of submission. I understand that in Ethereum we only have `now` to assist with block time but we don't have a time of a transaction, but that's not what I want.

Any ideas on how to do so, is it possible? Or if using a Dapp I'll have to do so via HTML or JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, `now` gives you the `block.timstamp`. On the Ethereum blockchain, this is the only timestamp built into the protocol.

The transaction you sent gets *processed* in the block that it is chosen in. Because of this, the "time of transaction" that you are looking for is actually *now*. The blockchain does not record the time that the transaction is intially created (and subsequently waiting to be included in a block).

If you are trying to store the time that your transaction is created, you will need to do that off-chain.